# Using a "#" Separator in fgetcsv?

Tags: php, csv

I used the http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php Documentation to use the fgetcsv function in order to import a csv file in my database (my server doesn't allows me to use the LOAD DATA INFILE sql function).

But my CSV files contains "#" character line separators and not a \n

I don't know how to make fgetcsv know that this is the line separator...

Here is my code:

```
    $file = fopen("Contenu/BD/test.csv", "r");
    fgetcsv($file);
    while(($data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE){
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c<$num; $c++){
            $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }

        ((INSERT SQL))

    }
    fclose($file);
```

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: If you have `#` as a record separator, you don't actually have a csv file; perhaps you should consider replacing `#` with `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my CSV files contains "#" character line separators and not a \n

Then this is not valid CSV file.

> I don't know how to make fgetcsv know that this is the line separator...

No, because this is not a valid line separator. You should make it valid CSV by replacing all these `#` with `\n` prior parsing.

*EDIT**

Then you either do 2 step import -> convert `#` to LFs and then use `fgetcsv()` or you can try to use [str_getcvs()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) instead, however that would require to read and keep whole input file in memory as you still will need to break the data into separate rows (i.e. with `explode()`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not my exported file. It's an external company that export the file into my ftp.